# How to deploy docker container in Github Action in yml file?

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, containers, github-actions

i have yml file in github action in workflow in that file there is a docker image build and that push to docker hub.

Now we want to execute that image and run as a container in github action workflow of same yml file.

How to do it ?

Here is the yml file

```
name: vampi_docker

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: docker login
      env:
#        Docker_Hub_Username: xxxxxx
#        Docker_Hub_Password: xxxxxx
        DOCKER_USER: ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}
        DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD}}
        repository: test/vampi_docker:latest
        tags: latest, ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
        
    - name: Build the Vampi Docker image
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag test/vampi_docker:latest
#        docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag vampi_docker:latest
        
    - name: List images
      run: docker images  
      
    - name: Docker Push
#      run: docker tag vampi_docker:latest ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}/vampi_docker:latest      
      run: docker push test/vampi_docker:latest
```

After Docker push next command should have Docker container i.e., building docker container in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already push image to remote, so in next step could just use `run` to run a container with that image, it will fetch the image from dockerhub or private registry:

```
- name: Run a container
  run: docker run --rm -it rashidmd/vampi_docker:latest
```

Comment: Thanks i solve it